# How to add custom functions to run in Selenium ActionChain/ActionBuilder?

Tags: python, selenium

I used to be able run custom function by appending to the _actions variable in ActionChain like below.

```
action = ActionChain(driver)
action._action.append(lambda: func())
```

It seems like [now](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py#L80) if drivers are w3c they are instead run by ActionBuilder object.  The ActionBuilder class [doesn't seem to](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c7dd3d3570b3f117225acd7353cbf7cf95a2686f/py/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/action_builder.py#L70) have a singular queue to run actions in order like ActionChains.  Anyone that is more familiar in selenium point me in the right direction?

Comment: The client used to send multiple commands to execute each step of a composite action. That's why it was possible to queue a function between the commands. It's no longer possible since a composite action executes as a single command. You'll have to call your function between two ActionChain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to beautifully consistently specify the actions, I advise you to make an interface to work with ActionBuild your own. Throw there all the actions and consistently perform

Something like this

```
class CustomActionChain:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.action = ActionChains(driver)
        self._actions = []

    def click(self, element):
        self._actions.append(lambda: self.action.click(element).perform())
        return self

    def custom_func(self, func):
        self._actions.append(func)
        return self

    def perform(self):
        for action in self._actions:
            action()
```